# How to import ruby gems (breakpoint) with webpack?

Tags: sass, webpack, breakpoint-sass

I've installed susy and sass, and set up the css/sass loader in the webpack config:

```
{ test: /\.scss$/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('css!sass') }
```

Here is my main scss file:

```
@import "~susy/sass/susy";
@import "breakpoint";

$susy: (
  columns: 12,
  gutters: 1/4,
  math: fluid,
  output: float,
  gutter-position: inside
);

.layout {
  @include container();
  @include layout(12 1/4);
}
```

This is an error in a webpack output

```
ERROR in ./src/styles/base.scss
Module build failed: ModuleBuildError: Module build failed: 
@import "breakpoint";
^
      File to import not found or unreadable: breakpoint
gems which are installed

viktors-mbp:~ viktor$ gem list breakpoint sass compass

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

breakpoint (2.7.0)

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

sass (3.4.22)
sassy-maps (0.4.0)

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

compass (1.1.0.alpha.3, 1.0.3)
compass-core (1.1.0.alpha.3, 1.0.3)
compass-import-once (1.0.5)
```

Does anyone know how to properly `@import` breakpoint ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you installed breakpoint-sass package:

`npm install breakpoint-sass --save-dev`

Then you have to import it, but "letting the SASS loader know" that this "breakpoint" element is outside the SASS folder, with the other node modules:

`@import '~breakpoint-sass/stylesheets/breakpoint';`

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `sass-loader` import [documentation](https://github.com/jtangelder/sass-loader):

> The sass-loader uses node-sass' custom importer feature to pass all queries to the webpack resolving engine. Thus you can import your Sass modules from node_modules. Just prepend them with a ~ to tell webpack that this is not a relative import.

and

> Writing @import "file" is the same as @import "./file".

pretty much describe the issue you're seeing.

### Solution

The answer to this would be to either install a [npm package for breakpoint](https://www.npmjs.com/package/breakpoint-sass) instead of the gem and import it from node_modules, as you did with `susy`. Or you could try to `@import` the full file path to the ruby gem.